# Conditional break point in Wolfram Workbench?

Tags: workbench

Is it possible to set up a conditional break point in Wolfram Workbench? For example I want the code to stop if an index `i` is equal to a given value.

Comment: you might consider posting this question in the new specialized site http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

Comment: Isn't it what I did ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way that works already is to put a break point inside an If statement.

```
If[condition,
   dummyInstruction;
];
```

And put a breakpoint at dummyInstruction. I don't know if something like this could be done without modifying the code in break point properties like in some other environments.